# How to detect the system shutdown event in the worker service .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, worker-service

In the window service for the .NET framework, we can override the **OnShutdown()** to do something before the system is turned off. I'm unable to find a similar solution for the worker service.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to track System shutdown or your Application shutdown?

Comment: I'm looking to track System shutdown.

Comment: AFAIK the worker service is something used within ASP core, while shutdown is something normally tracked within a windows service. So within a web server it is enough to track the closing of the application, while within a windows service you can track shutting down the system.

Comment: @Oliver make sense, so is there any way we can track if the system is shutting down or if any similar solution for worker service?

Comment: Almost always, shutdown is the wrong time to be running code. You never have enough context to know how urgent the shutdown actually is and so how much is a reasonable amount of time to be running code before someone intervenes and pulls out the power cord.

Comment: public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {} is the closest thing you can get in BackgroundService